# Why does this function always return either 0 or 1

Tags: java, recursion, return

I'm trying to learn something about recursion so I'm tryin' to do some exercises but now I'm kind of stucked because I can't figure out why does this function always return me 1 or 0
Im trying to count number of appearences of 11 in int array.

```
public class Uloha06 {
public static int count = 0;
public static int array11(int[] nums, int index){
    if(index<nums.length){
        if(nums[index]==11)
            count+=1;
        index++;
        array11(nums,index);
        if(index<nums.length)
            return index;
    } 
    return count;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int array11[]={11,1,2,36,11};
    System.out.println(array11(array11, 0));
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you are not doing anything with the results from your recursive calls `array11(nums,index);` - if this returns a count of 1 what happens to it? You should be adding it to the count variable?

Comment: Java uses pass-by-value, so the `count` will be updated at most once.

Comment: What is the purpose of `if(index<nums.length) return index;`?

Comment: @Pshemo wow, you just solved my problem, it was enough to return count. It seemed pretty much clear  that I should return index :D now when I look at it I feel really dumb :D thx man

Comment: BTW you should avoid using fields in recursion (like `counter`). For instance you can use same technique which we could use with writing recursive sum which could look like `return currentElement + recursiceSumOfPreviousElements`. Here your `currentElement` will be either 1 or 0 depending if value at current index is 11 or not. So your recursion can look like `public static int count11(int[] nums, int index){
        if (index < nums.length)
            return (nums[index] == 11 ? 1 : 0) + count11(nums, index + 1);
        else
            return 0;
    }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It returns `0` for an empty array, and `1` for a non-empty array. The result you see came from `index`, not from `count` as you are expecting.

I would write it without a field involved.

```
public int m(int[] nums, int index, int count) {
    return index < nums.length ?
            m(nums, index + 1, nums[index] == 11 ? ++count : count) :
            count;
}
```

or (suggested by @Pshemo in the comments)

```
public int m(int[] nums, int index) {
    return index < nums.length ?
            (nums[index] == 11 ? 1 : 0) + m(nums, ++index) :
            0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You return the index. Marked your problem:

```
public class Uloha06 {
    public static int count = 0;
    public static int array11(int[] nums, int index){
        if(index<nums.length){
             if(nums[index]==11)
                 count+=1;
             index++;
             array11(nums,index);
             /// booom here index is 1 but you want count
             //if(index<nums.length)
             //    return index;
         } 
         return count;
     }
     public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int array11[]={11,1,2,36,11};
        System.out.println(array11(array11, 0));
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
public static int array11(int[] nums, int index){

if(index < 0){
    return 0;}

 else if (nums [index] == 11)
 { 
        return (array11(nums, index-1) + 1);

 }
   else {
      return  array11(nums, index-1);

   }

}
```